# What does it mean: unified memory is not user accessible?

Tags: memory, apple-silicon

I am seeing on mac M2 max site that
`note: unified memory is not user accessible. if you think you’ll need additional memory, consider upgrading at the time of purchase.`

What does it mean?

Does it impact any activity from a developer(Machine Learning Engineer) perspective e.g. training models, etc? What are pros/cons of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It just means that you cannot 'upgrade' the memory after purchase, eg. buy a machine with 8GB and then swap chips about to have 16GB. It is integrated into the processor.

It will have no bearing on your development other than, as the blurb suggests, to correctly size your machine to your requirements before purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's new architecture is known as System on a Chip [SoC].

Essentially this means *everything* - CPU, GPU, also a neural engine, digital signal processor, Image processor, video encoding, secure enclave … RAM [Unified memory] are all on the same chip.

All this makes the processing very fast and efficient - but it means no part of it is upgradeable later.

You need, therefore, to buy the configuration you need right at the outset. You can't change your mind later.

See - [Why Are The Apple M1, M1 Pro And M1 Max Chips So Fast?](https://www.production-expert.com/production-expert-1/why-are-the-apple-m1-m1-pro-and-m1-max-chips-so-fast)